# How do I wait for an event to finish and access callback vars outside of the scope in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, electron

I've searched through dozens of sites but haven't really found a solution for my problem.

First of all I want to wait for 'response' callback to finish execution but I'm not sure how I'm able to achieve this. Promise and async/await didn't really help me or at least I'm not sure how to use it in this particular situation.

Secondly how can I make response available outside of this callback event.
`response_ = response` didn't work.

```
let response_ = null

request = net.request(specific_info['host'])
request.on('response', (response) => {
   // here I want something like response_ = response

   console.log(`STATUS: ${response.statusCode}`)
   console.log(`HEADERS: ${JSON.stringify(response.headers)}`)
   response.on('data', (chunk) => {
     console.log(`BODY: ${chunk}`)
   })
   response.on('end', () => {
     console.log('No more data in response.')
   })
 })
request.end()

// here I want to wait until 'response' finished execution
console.log(`STATUS: ${response_.statusCode})
```

The framework I'm using is Electron

Comment: So your advice would be to just pass a different method to the 'response' callback and add the next logic inside that and call it from there?

Comment: This is one option, in linked answer you can find more, like wrapping this in `Promise`